# Face Recognition (2D Array) Confidence Formula Derivation

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

confidence = 1.0f - sqrt( distSq / (float)(nTrainFaces * nEigens) ) / 255.0f

1. Why it is divided by (nTrainFaces*nEigens)?

Comment: high voodoo factor involved here ;)

Comment: i never understood, why nTrainFaces shows up in the calculation

Comment: Is this the tutorial you mention: http://www.shervinemami.info/faceRecognition.html ? Could you link the correct one in your post, so we get the right context

Comment: Hi Buella, yes that's correct one, im referring its full coding in [Link](http://www.shervinemami.info/onlineFaceRec_Linux.zip)

Answer (score 1):

> **Why it is divided by (nTrainFaces*nEigens)?**

Well, if you're just trying to find the confidence value for the 'test face eigenvectors (or values?)' with just 1 and only trained face, then you'd do something like

```
confidence = 1.0f - (sqrt( least_squared_distance / no_of_eigens ) / 255.0)
```

However, since you're finding nearest neighbour within trained face database, you want the confidence to reflect that your nearest neighbour gives a high confidence value for one of the faces in your trained database, amongst all the trained faces. Thus the confidence now is calculated not against 1 trained face, but with all trained faces, thus

```
confidence = 1.0f - (sqrt( least_squared_distance / no_of_trained_faces * no_of_eigens ) / 255.0)
```

> **"leastDistSq=DBL_MAX" what is DBL_MAX**

least_squared_distance = DBL_MAX is basically a safe way from saying least_squared_distance = 99999999, since depending on the platform, hardware, or implementation, that might cause buffer overflow. So DBL_MAX is standard library that represents the largest double value.

And this is how it finds the least squared distance

```
if(distSq < leastDistSq) {
  leastDistSq = distSq;
  iNearest = iTrain;
}
```