# Face Recognition Classifier

Tags: c++, c, opencv, classification, face-recognition

By referring to the previous [***post***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791971/eigen-face-recognition-2d-array-confidence-formula-derivation), the method used for classification was Euclidean Distance with Nearest Neighbor. However, the result obtained is not accurate as both known dataset and unknown dataset are giving similarity 99%. Even with  Mahalanobis distance also gives similar result.

Is there any other method for face recognition classification? Could you provide me some examples/formulae?

```
float d_i = projectedTestFace[i] - projectedTrainFaceMat->data.fl[iTrain*nEigens + i];
distSq += d_i*d_i; // Euclidean distance
```

Answer (score 1):

imho, if you get bad results, blame your input, not the distance formula

without any further preprocessing(alignment,cropping,equalization), even a plain L2 norm over the pixels gives better results, than eigenfaces. (sad truth here)

since 2.4.2, opencv has [face-recognition out of-the-box](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html). (also with alternative fisher and lbph features)

you probably should use that, instead of rolling your own (and please use the c++ api, not the arcane c one).

if you do want to stick with eigenfaces, you still could try the L2 distance beween a 'reconstructed' (from the eigenvecs) image and the test image as a confidence measure, as [done here](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/blob/master/Chapter8_FaceRecognition/recognition.cpp#L164) (by shervin, again)

Comment: I did alignment, resize and histogramEqualization but the result still same. Im trying L2 distance, but the result obtained is "-nan" @berak

Answer (score 0):

```
// Compare two images by getting the L2 error (square-root of sum of squared error).
double getSimilarity(const Mat A, const Mat B)
{
if (A.rows > 0 && A.rows == B.rows && A.cols > 0 && A.cols == B.cols) {
    // Calculate the L2 relative error between the 2 images.
    double errorL2 = norm(A, B, CV_L2);
    // Convert to a reasonable scale, since L2 error is summed across all pixels of the image.
    double similarity = errorL2 / (double)(A.rows * A.cols);
    return similarity;
}
else {
    //cout << "WARNING: Images have a different size in 'getSimilarity()'." << endl;
    return 100000000.0;  // Return a bad value
}
}
```

I wonder why i always get return 100000000. Does it means that the preprocessed and reconstructed face have difference size? That's why it skips the L2 distance comparison?

Below are part of my coding:

```
Mat j =projectedTestFace[i];
Mat k =projectedTrainFaceMat>data.fl[iTrain*nEigens + i];
similarity=getSimilarity(j,k);
```

without the else statement, i get similarity=-nan result, wondering what are -nan and -inf stand for.

Comment: "Does it means that the preprocessed and reconstructed face have difference size?" - yes. but please don#t skip it, instead adjust the image size

Comment: Mat k is something thresholded ? (i don't get: `data.fl[iTrain*nEigens + i]` , as  `iTrain*nEigens + i` does not look like a valid index to me)

Comment: Im currently working with Cambridge face database, which has all standard size 112x92, im testing with one of its sample 112x92 too. Got no idea why it still indicate difference size. Mat k is the database face to be compared with test face, Mat k refers to the 1st Eigenface location (stored in 2D array). Thats from my understanding. Im still asking from the previous post [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22791971/eigen-face-recognition-2d-array-confidence-formula-derivation) @berak

Comment: hmm, an expression like `Mat a,b; a = b>17;` does a threshold. i don't your usage of '>' there. also , `data.fl` must refer to a CvMat, not to a cv::Mat. mixing deprecated c-api functions/structures  with c++ is a receipe for desaster

Comment: oh, looking at your prev. post makes it a bit clearer. i think, you got that from here: `float d_i = projectedTestFace[i]-projectedTrainFaceMat>data.fl[iTrain*nEigens + i];` (the '>' should have been a '->' (pointer access), no ?

Comment: and no, you don't compare it to the 1st eigenface, but to a *reconstructed* image. see shervin's code [here](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/blob/master/Chapter8_FaceRecognition/main.cpp#L463) and [here](https://github.com/MasteringOpenCV/code/blob/master/Chapter8_FaceRecognition/recognition.cpp#L123)

Comment: yes it was my typing error, suppose to be "->", im confuse with C & C++ api in opencv. I tried in C, getSimilarity(const IplImage A, const IplImage B) i got a lot errors and .cols .rows not found. I'm current working with Shervin Face Recognition in C API in previous post, because his new program in C++ API doesnt support offline recognition. @berak

Comment: k,k. in general, avoid IplImages and the whole deprecated c-api. really, prefer the Mastering_opencv code to shervin's old website (or whatever you find on SO)

Comment: do-not-use-the-c-api. (only morons shoot their foot twice, to be sure)